# "Run First Aid from Recovery" while in Recovery

Tags: macos, disk-utility, recovery

I have a late-2013 Retina Macbook Pro running Sierra 10.12.5 with a myriad of issues that I've been trying to work out. Today's problem: First Aid says there are problems with the partition map that might prevent booting, and to fix them, I need to run First Aid from Recovery. Easy enough.

So I boot into Recovery and run First Aid and get the same message: run First Aid from Recovery, even though I'm already in Recovery. I get the same message in Internet Recovery and when running Disk Utility off an external macOS installer USB. How can I get First Aid to run in Recovery?

Comment: The error message might be dumb. What happens when you repair the Macintosh HD, then the Disk that contains the HD, then the Macintosh HD a second time? Clean run the final time?

Answer (score 3):

I think it means restart from [Internet recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). Because the disk containing the recovery partition you are running disk first aid from needs repair. So reboot while holding <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Give your ethernet or wifi password if needed.

This just happened to me.

*edit* to fix key sequence.

*edit* I missed that you were already in Internet Recovery. Depending on the error, it may just be uncorrectable.

Comment: It's CMD+ALT+R. This works fine though, the message you get from Disk Util is really bad.

Comment: @Marv correct.  I updated this (I'd prefer to use option than alt, despite what the paint  says)

Comment: I first tried `command+option+r` and that showed the Internet Recovery globe animation, but still gave me the same error. I then tried `command+shift+option+r` and that showed the same globe animation, but then started in me in an older recovery version that allowed me to repair the disk.

Comment: None of these key sequences worked for me unfortunately

Comment: @forresthopkinsa what happened? Did internet recovery ever start?

Comment: @StevenR.Loomis Whatever key sequences I was using, they were booting me in an older recovery version which didn't support APFS or whatever filesystem was on the disk. I needed to go back to the newer recovery version. I don't remember how I did that, I just kept trying different keystrokes until I got it to work. I did *not* need to boot from an external recovery disk.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa yes, that would be a problem. Probably it went back to a pre-APFS  version.

Answer (score -2):

Mount the drive below the physical drive name then check that via first aid worked well for me

Answer (score -3):

Restart your Mac in Recovery Mode by holding down Cmd+R immediately after the chime. You'll booth into Recovery Mode and you'll see Disk Utility as an option. Run Disk Utility, select Macintosh HD and run First Aid.

More details: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: You did not answer his question. He was already in Recovery Mode.