# Mac asks me to run Disk Utility in Recovery, while in Recovery

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, recovery

I have a WD EasyStore Drive, and for some reason it was bugging out with Time Machine today. I decided to run First Aid on the drive and it found a corruption it wanted me to fix via Recovery mode. That seemed easy enough, so I booted into Recovery mode, and proceeded to run First Aid from there only to find it give me the exact same message.

How do I run First Aid on my drive?

Comment: Check out the answers from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290371/run-first-aid-from-recovery-while-in-recovery. Looks like you may need to try Internet Recovery

Comment: @PoisonNinja that seems to be a different scenario as the Disk being repaired is the one with the Recovery. Will try it out though

Comment: @PoisonNinja Same thing happens in Internet Recovery.

Comment: You don't need to be in recovery mode when attempting to repair an external disk as you can unmount it from the system.

Comment: @Allan It is asking me to go into Recovery Mode when I attempt it logged in. It also says the same thing in Recovery Mode, so I am not sure.